# Routing with apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do friendly url with apache and php, I try with this method :
A .htaccess with fallback ressource :

```
FallbackResource /route.php
DirectoryIndex route.php
```

And my route.php file (just a test for the moment) :

```
<?php echo "url=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

If I try to access `/test`, it display `url=/test`, but if I try with `/home` apache display the content of the folder /var/www, how can I fix it ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have parameters in your links?like    ?url=test

Comment: Directory home exists but test doesn't. Does it?

Comment: test and home doesn't exist, it's just to try, route.php will route the user, for the moment I don't need to create page, I just want to be always redirected to route.php from all url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect all urls to route.php, use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/route.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /route.php?url=$1  [L]
```

Comment: * and don't bother with the apache settings like DirectoryIndex  or FallbackResource